# Get the count of unique words from all .txt files in a directory

Tags: php, arrays, unique, file-get-contents, cpu-word

I have a directory of text files. I want to loop through each of the text files in the directory and get the overall count of unique words (count of vocabulary), not for each individual file, but for ALL the files together. In other words, I want the number of unique words within all the files together, and NOT the number of unique words for each individual file.

For example, I have three text files in a directory. Here are their contents:

file1.txt -> `here is some text.`

file2.txt -> `here is more text.`

file3.txt -> `even more text.`

So the count of unique words for this directory of text files in this case is 6.

I have tried to use this code:

```
$files = glob("C:\\wamp\\dir");

$out = fopen("mergedFiles.txt", "w");


  foreach($files as $file){
      $in = fopen($file, "r");
      while ($line = fread($in)){
           fwrite($out, $line);
      }
      fclose($in);
  }


  fclose($out);
```

to merge all the text files and then after using this code I planned to use the array_unique() on mergedFiles.txt. However, the code is not working.

How can I get the unique word count of all the text files in the directory in the best way possible?

Comment: `However, the code is not working` how exactly it is not working?

Comment: I don't think you need to merge all the text together just open the files consecutively. Read in each line, remove punctuation and normalise the case. split into words and add to a set or as the keys (not the values) to an associative array storing the count for that word in the value. In the end the size of the array/set is the number of unique words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$allWords = array();

foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) // loop on each file
{
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename); // Get file contents
    $words = explode(' ', $contents); // Make an array with words

    if ( $words )
        $allWords = array_merge($allWords, $words); // combine global words array and file words array
}

var_dump(count(array_unique($allWords)));
```

**EDIT** Other version which :

- remove dots
- remove multiple spaces
- match word if missing space between end of sentence and new one.

---

```
function removeDot($string) {
    return rtrim($string, '.');
}

$words = explode(' ', preg_replace('#\.([a-zA-Z])#', '. $1', preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$contents)));
$words = array_map("removeDot", $words);
```

Comment: That's an overkill and also not all words end on a space to explode them on. What about the word on which a sentence ends?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky : Last word will also be in array with explode. `explode(' ', 'here is some text.')` will return 4 words.

Comment: That is only for 1 sentence. What about https://eval.in/229773 and even in the case you mentioned are you saying that `text.` is a word? nope `text` is; without a period.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky you're right. Code edited with other version to match specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have legitimate reasons not to simply concatenate the files and process their content as a concatenated string, use this snippet to target txt files in a directory, join their texts, make the text lowercase, isolate words, remove duplicates, then count unique words:

Code (not fully tested on a filesystem): ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vuKZI))

```
echo count(
    array_unique(
        str_word_count(
            strtolower(
                implode(
                    ' ',
                    array_map(
                        'file_get_contents',
                        glob("*.txt")
                    )
                )
            ),
            1
        )
    )
);
```

Assuming texts from file:

```
[
    'here is some text.',
    'here is more text.',
    'even more text.'
]
```

The output is `6` from a unique array of:

```
array (
  0 => 'here',
  1 => 'is',
  2 => 'some',
  3 => 'text',
  6 => 'more',
  8 => 'even',
)
```

Modify the snippet as needed: perhaps use a different technique/algorithm to identify "words", or use `mb_strtolower()`, or don't use `strtolower()` at all.